# Plotting complex inequalities in maple

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, maple

I'm having trouble plotting a set of complex numbers in maple. I'm trying to plot the set

$$S = \lbrace z \in \Bbb C : 1 \leq \lvert z\rvert \leq 2, \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \lvert \arg(z)\rvert \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\rbrace.$$

I know what it should look like from a drawing I produced but I'd like to plot it in maple. My code is as follows;

```
z := x + I*y;

plots:-implicitplot([abs(z) <= 2, abs(z) <= 1, abs(arg(z)) >= Pi/4,
                     abs(arg(z)) <= Pi/2], x = -3...3, y = -3...3, filled = true);
```

The issue is that the inequalities are being plotted independently of each other rather than all together, so even the first pair of inequalities together fill the entire plane. Is there any way I can have the $4$ conditions imposed in $S$ be taken into account at the same time, rather than separately?

Comment: @Masacroso I considered doing this but I'm not sure how it works; introducing an *and* between the first two inequalities just spits out an error.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=boolean). Try to use an AND expression inside of an "if... then" statement. Sorry, I dont know how maple works... I did a [very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949105/plotting-sets-in-bbb-r2-or-bbb-c-in-some-cas) some days ago with not very useful answers... I hope you had more luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
restart;

z := x + I*y:

plots:-implicitplot( piecewise( (abs(z) <= 2) and (abs(z) >= 1)
                                and (abs(argument(z)) >= Pi/4)
                                and (abs(argument(z)) <= Pi/2),
                                false, true),
                     x=-3...3, y=-3...3,
                     gridrefine=3, view=[-3..3,-3..3] );
```

[image]

Comment: While it may interest you how `implicitplot` can succeed here, Carl's answer to the same question posed by you on stackoverflow, which used `inequal` rather than `implicitplot`, is better IMO. The edges are smoother, presumably because some symbolic solving is done. In contrast, the first argument to `implicitplot` above gets treated more like a black-box, hence the need to ramp up the `gridrefine` option just to get a passably smooth result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883436/plotting-in-maple

Comment: Agreed, thanks for your answer anyway. I posted the same in stackoverflow because I wasn't seeing any answers here and feared the post had been lost in the stream of other questions